# How can I display video as an overlay on markers detected by ARToolKit?

Tags: iphone, ipad, augmented-reality, artoolkit

I'm using ARToolKit to develop an iOS augmented reality application based on the detection of 2-D markers in the environment.  I'd like to be able to overlay video on these markers, but I'm not sure how to do this.

How would I use ARToolKit to overlay video on specific markers within a live camera feed?

Comment: As a note, ARToolKit is a library licensed under the GPL, so you will not be able to make non-GPL iPhone application using it unless you pay for a commercial license from ARToolworks.

Comment: We have the commercial license. Anyone have links/tutorials how I can play a video file on AR Camera view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ARToolKit for iOS (from ARToolworks) includes an example of movie overlay since release 4 (released August 2011). The example is called ARAppMovie.

Answer (score 1):

Benjamin Loulier has a [sample VRToolKit application](http://www.benjaminloulier.com/posts/5-virtual-reality-on-iphone-code-inside) where he uses ARToolKitPlus (derived from ARToolKit) to use the iPhone camera to track markers, then place 3-D objects over them.  He created a wrapper around ARToolKit's marker recognition code that provides a callback with the model view matrix that encodes information about position and orientation of this marker in the scene.

You could do something similar, only instead of overlaying a CAEAGLLayer like he does, you could place your video within a standard CALayer and transform that layer to match the rotation and placement of the object within the scene.  Learning from his code (which is under GPL, so you probably can't use it directly), you should be able to overlay your video on the scene without requiring a lot of code of your own.

Comment: Thanks you very much for the information. But in this VRToolKit it's hard to add our own markers.. Do you have any idea regarding markers?

Comment: @Aruna - Contact the people at ARToolworks: http://www.artoolworks.com/ .  I've seen them do some very impressive work with finding custom markers, and they'd probably be willing to help you out with this if you're licensing their framework.

Comment: @ArunaLakmal Have you found a way to add our own marker in VRTolkit?

Comment: @ArunaFromLK i am facing same problem,i cant add own marker files.did you complete it?help me,if u completed this

Comment: I'm sorry. I didn't try this yet. There should be an easy way to add markers now. I was trying long ago.